# extract features from image database in simpleCV

Tags: feature-extraction, getimagedata, simplecv

I am new to python, therefore I need some help:
**AIM: I have an image database containing 10 images. I want to use a hue feature extractor to extract the hue from each image and store it in a list and compare the list with hues from other images not belonging to the databae
Now this code works fine for me for a single image e.g.:**

```
print __doc__
from SimpleCV import*
from SimpleCV import HueHistogramFeatureExtractor, np
import numpy as np
    image1 = ...
    image2 = ...

    hue = HueHistogramFeatureExtractor() # define the extractor      
    x = np.array(hue.extract(image1))  # extract features
    y = np.array(hue.extract(image2))  # extract features

    xandy = np.sum(np.square(x-y)) # compare extracted features

    print xandy

    ('#######################################################')
    Of course avoiding to write each image seperatly from a database I tried: 

    imageDatabase = "/.../dir/car/" #load image database
    car_images = ImageSet(imageDatabase)
    hue = HueHistogramFeatureExtractor() # define the extractor 
    car_hue = [hue.extract(car_images) for c in car_image] # extract hue features from image database???  
    print hue # print hue feature list
```

Do I am on the right track? Please give me direction to work to.

Comment: Please add details. What do you expect? What problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

So the hue histogram extractor extracts a histogram of hues, not a single average hue value (which it appears to be what you want to do). Have you tried meanColor? Also if you use the [SimpleCV help forum](http://help.simplecv.org/questions/) we might be able to better support your questions.